# Any other way to read/write a PDF file using java application other than itext, PDFbox?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox

I Tried with iText and PDFBox .
It is not simple , we need to understand lot of code for this.
Can anybody provide a simple way of reading and writing PDF using Java Application.
Make sure the application is standalone, and no need of any web/application server.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of simple examples for manipulating PDFs with Itext in the Itext in Action Book.

PDF is a complex file format. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have one application in which user can download a page what he/she is viewing, in the form of PDF.Need a PDF tool to be incorporated into my J2EE webapp. The user is on a given page which has bunch of text paragraphs. User clicks "Download PDF", the application will convert the page to PDF and show Save dialog.

Comment: So you want an HTML to PDF conversion tool?